# How to initialize state variable such that get request is made on the current url?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to generate url based on the `params` data

Here is the code:

```
const Feeds = () => {

 const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
        switch (params.category) {
            case "news_National":
                setUrl("http://localhost:8090/newsOnAir/national");
                break;

            case "news_International":
                setUrl("http://localhost:8090/newsOnAir/international");
                break;

             case "XYZ":
                navigate("/home");
                break;

            ...........
            ...........}

           axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
               console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

     },[params.category])



   return (........)
}
```

But the problem occurs when the `get request` is made to the previous URL state data. When a `get request` is made at that time the old data persists then the state is changed.

I cannot eliminate the use of `useEffect` since the switch case has `navigate` logic for some cases.

Please guide me on how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need of using `useEffect` here. See [Updating state based on props or state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state).

Define a function to calculate `url`

```js
function getUrl(category) {
  // calculate url here based on params.category
}

// then simply use the url by calling function

const Feeds = () => {

  const url = getUrl(params.category)

  // ... rest of code

}
```

Comment: I cannot eliminate use of useEffect since i do use ``navigate`` inside my switch case

Comment: you can just use `navigate` for that specific case I guess

Answer (score -1):

React setState method is **asynchronous**, which means that even if you called your "setState" method, it will not ensure that your state is updated **immediately**.

To bypass this, you can either :

use setState callback, which ensures that your state has been updated, like this :

```
setUrl(url, () => {
    //url is now updated with the right value
});
```

or put your Api call inside an useEffect hook, where you check the value of url like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (url !== "")
   {
      //Here your url should be OK
   }
}, [url])
```

Comment: The logic to change the URL is inside the useEffect. Passing the URL as second argument will mean that the code inside useEffect will execute only when URL changes. Since the URL change logic is never visited the application state remains same for every new route.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer, I meant an other useEffect to do your Api call, OR your apiCall in the callback of setState method.
And yes, your url change logic is visited in your useEffect, according to the code you posted